# iOS 9 Core Data Threading

Tags: multithreading, core-data, ios9

I have a problem with Core Data in iOS 9 I didn't have in iOS 8.

I have an environment with multiple `NSManagedObjectContext` objects. Parent `context` is of concurrency type `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and all view controllers have their own child `context` objects. The reason I'm using this kind of system is because I want to have more independent `contexts` and merge them only when I decide it should be done. Child `context` is on private queue because it does its work on back thread and then parent `context`, which is on main thread propagate changes to DB and does what it needs on main thread.

All of this worked just fine until iOS 9. Behaviour I'm getting is rather strange. For example, when I add new object of type A, it propagates to storage. If I add another object of type A on same vc, using same `context` but from another button, `performBlockAndWait:` of moc is not being called and my app freezes without any messages in the console. If try using first button, it passes every time.

```
- (BOOL)saveChildContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)childContext
{
[childContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSError* error;

    [childContext save:&error];

    [_managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        NSError* parentError;
        [_managedObjectContext save:&parentError];
    }];
}];
```

}

If I call `performBlock:`, everything is fine in both cases. So i figured out that this might be due to some wrong threading. On the other hand, using same thread with same type of object, but another button, everything goes nicely. This is what confuses me, and brings doubt that it has to do with threads.

My questions:

1) Is the correct way to have child `context` objects on back threads, and have `context` that saves to DB and gets back to GUI on main thread, or is there a better convention, and if there is, why?

2) The code worked on iOS 8. Still, it seems that it won't enter `performBlockAndWait:` method. Why is that this block doesn't get executed sometimes? Is it possible that some other thread is blocking? How to find out if this is the case?

Comment: To troubleshoot your specific problem with the buttons you have to post the code that shows the difference between the two buttons.

Comment: I thought problem might be in that, since other option never caused deadlock or anything else. Somehow, I used two different contexts. I really don't know how I managed to establish a relationship between two objects fetched by two different contexts. What is still strange is that when I call asynchronous performBlock:, it still gets to DB without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out (thank you Mundi) that one of my classes initialized its own `NSManagedObjectContext` object for fetching some data. Later I related objects fetched from different contexts. Somehow, I could do that, although it shouldn't be possible and must be avoided even trying to connect objects that way. Always use same context for dealing with objects that have relationships between them.

So, I ended up using `childContext = someObjet.managedObjectContext;` to get the reference to correct context, instead of `childContext = [dbClient createChildContext];` which returned new context.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful you should at least up-vote it.

Comment: Sure, sorry. Thank you once again. I hate when I don't get a credit for helping someone ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your setup is not ideal. Why use a background context in a view controller? View controllers are UI interfaces and should use the main context.

In your code sample, you are using the main context in a background thread which I think is problematic.

Here is a standard setup that works well (including iOS9).

```
rootContext (Private Queue)   --> saves to persistent store --> has child
mainContext (Main Queue)      --> used in UI                --> has children
workerContext (Private Queue) --> create at will to do background stuff
```

In this way saving to the persistent store always comes last and always occurs in the background. This is very safe and performs well.

I use *ad hoc* worker contexts e.g. for saving stuff on a background queue after retrieving from a server, or to handle object editing that can be canceled (you just throw away the context). Saving the worker context will update the UI (because changes are "pushed up" to the main context which can respond via e.g. a `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods or `NSNotificationCenter`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and suggestions. As I said, I wanted to perform some background task on another thread, keeping main thread for GUI. Could using only other threads be a solution? If I always notified GUI dispaching messages on main thread, I might not use main thread at all for data work. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. This is also encapsulated in my answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. If the parent context is on main thread, it would update GUI, but if there's a lot of work to be done with DB, then it would take some time on main thread. On the other hand, if this time consuming operation was on some other thread, it could do its job and after it was done, it could just notifiy main thread, right?